# Unable to Access Subdirectory in GitHub Repository with Nested Git Repositories

Tags: git, github

Title: Unable to Access Subdirectory in GitHub Repository with Nested Git Repositories

Description:
I have a directory structure where I have a folder1 containing its own .git directory and a folder2 nested within folder1, also containing its own .git directory. Each of these directories has its own separate remote URL. However, after pushing folder1 to url1, I'm unable to access folder2 in the GitHub repository. When navigating to folder2, I encounter a 404 error.

I've attempted to address this issue by using Git submodules, but the problem persists. You can see the error in this screenshot.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/In14v.png)

How can I resolve this issue and ensure that both folder1 and folder2 are accessible in the GitHub repository after pushing changes?

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: [tag:git-submodules] , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+nested+repositories